# I want my Ember.js conditionals to load different templates upon toggling a boolean

Tags: javascript, html, view, ember.js

The javascript seems to be getting called because im seeing **the console.logs being triggered but no actual HTML is being displayed**

Usually I will put this as an action in the controller, but since I want the javascript to load when the page itself loads, I injected it into the view using willInsertElement.

```
VpcYeoman.DocView = Ember.View.extend({ 
  toggleLetterSwitch: false,
  togglePermitSwitch: false,  
  templateName: 'doc',
  willInsertElement: function() {
      var docTemplateID = this.get('docTemplateID');
      if ( docTemplateID == 2) {
        this.set('toggleLetterSwitch', true);
        this.set('togglePermitSwitch', false);
        console.log('docTemplateID equals 2');
      } else {
        this.set('toggleLetterSwitch', false);
        this.set('togglePermitSwitch', true);
        console.log(this.get('toggleLetterSwitch'));
        console.log('docTemplateID else 1');
      }
  }
});
```

--  doc.hbs  --

```
{{#if toggleLetterSwitch}}
  <h1>Showing Letter Template</h1>
{{/if}}

{{#if togglePermitSwitch}}
<h1>Showing Permit Template</h1>
{{/if}}
```

Even if no docTemplateID is found, the function should still toggle the default template.

Comment: when the code evaluates the ifs, it tries to find toggleLetterSwitch in the controller and in the model, so, it does not find it. Change the ifs, to #if view.toggleLetterSwitch and see if that works.

Comment: It did work! It's only toggling the togglePermitSwitch because it's not finding the templateID for some reason, but that's for another question.

Comment: probably because docTemplateID exists on your controller/model ;)  this.get('controller.docTemplateID')...

Comment: You are correct, kingpin. Here is a link to the proper question for this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23742150/i-want-my-view-to-grab-the-value-of-an-attribute

Comment: @fanta Do you mind adding your comment as an answer so I can check it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure, you should change your ifs, like this:

```
{{#if view.toggleLetterSwitch}}
```

the thing is that toggleLetterSwitch exists in your view, not in the controller nor in the model.

Comment: Why do I add 'view.' in front of toggleLetterSwitch, but not 'controller.' when I'm calling something from the controller?

Comment: in your VpcYeoman.DocView you're setting this.set('toggleLetterSwitch', true); so, toggleLetterSwitch lives in your view.